# user defined type variable is not clearing the value inside the transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have scenario to use the Temporary user defined type variable in transaction, but the temporary variable is not clearing the value inside the transaction.

```
CREATE TYPE [int_list_table] AS TABLE([item_id] [int] NULL) 
GO

DECLARE @int_val BIGINT

-- Create a Temp table with 5 rows
;WITH TEMP(int_val)
AS
(SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
SELECT int_val = 1 + int_val FROM TEMP WHERE int_val < 5
)SELECT * INTO #int FROM TEMP;

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE IntCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT int_val FROM #int

OPEN IntCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM IntCursor INTO @int_val

WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        -- a temprory table to store the integer value
        DECLARE @table [int_list_table]
        INSERT INTO @table
        SELECT 1 WHERE 2 = @int_val         
        -- Actually @table should have resultset only at @int_val = 2, But once it filled with values even for 3 and 4
        SELECT 
            'User Table Type Value' = item_id,
            'Loop Integer Value' = @int_val
        FROM 
            @table          
        COMMIT TRANSACTION 
    END TRY    
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK 
    END CATCH   
    FETCH NEXT FROM IntCursor INTO @int_val
END
CLOSE IntCursor
DEALLOCATE IntCursor
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

For the above query the output is

[image: Actually it has to return only the record for 2, but it is not clearing the value once it is initialized. Please guide me to proceed further.]

Actually it has to return only the record for 2, but it is not clearing the value once it is initialized. Please guide me to proceed further.

Comment: Why do you think the table should be emptied or that variables should be cleared after a transaction has been committed? It's still the same batch. And as Mikael points out table variables aren't affected by a transaction (this is why you can stuff data into a @table variable and still query that data after a rollback).

Comment: I posted the Sample one, actually based on criteria need to fill the temp variable, that variable need to send for bulk insertion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of the data type does not clear the content of the table. Once the table variable is there it will have whatever you have put into it. The execution of the code does not even have to **pass** the place where the variable is declared. This will work as well.

```
 if 0 = 1
 begin
   DECLARE @table [int_list_table]
 end
```

You only have to make sure that the declaration is before any references to the variable.

To fix your code so it does what you want you can of course add `delete from @table` just before the insert statement.

Comment: Yes it fixed my problem, why the declaration is not clearing the value. How the metadata information is enough for declaring the table variable.

Comment: @VIJAY - It is the same for **all** types of variables in TSQL. If you put a declaration in a loop, the values assigned will still be there and not set to `null` as one could think it should.

Comment: @VIJAY - You should also know that table variables is not part a transaction so the code that handles the transaction does nothing in your sample.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation on `TSQL variables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953.aspx);

> The scope of a variable lasts from the point it is declared until the
>   end of the batch or stored procedure in which it is declared.

Since your whole example as far as I can tell is a single batch, your `@table` variable never goes out of scope, and therefore keeps its values until the batch ends.